# C# get image type, not using the image file extension

Tags: c#, jpeg

I am looking for C# code to get the image file format by parsing the file content.

Answer (score 4):

You can read and check first few bytes of a file. It's called *signature*.

For example for JPEG it's `FF D8 FF`

[Here is one of signature databases](http://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=all&order=SIGNATURE&sort=DESC). I'm sure you can google more.